# Read GZip Compressed file into datatable, then parse this data into another datatable

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable

I have an application which reads and parses txt files into datatables (for upload later). Some of these files are compressed (GZip). I have gotten as far as to identify and read the compressed files into a datatable with a single row (basically a reproduction of the file). What I need to do now is parse this data (on "|") into another datatable (or in-situ in the same datatable if possible).

```
    var ReadTable = new DataTable();
                    ReadTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
                    ReadTable.Columns.Add("Col2");
                    ReadTable.Columns.Add("Col3");
                    ReadTable.Columns.Add("Col4");
                    ReadTable.Columns.Add("Col5");

                    var ZipReadTable = new DataTable();
                    ZipReadTable.Columns.Add("ZipCol1");

                    if (isZip == false)
                    {
                        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(FileLocationNameOriginal);
                        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                        parser.SetDelimiters("|");
                        //Read and parse all data in the file into a datatable
                        while (!parser.EndOfData)
                        {
                            ReadTable.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields());
                        }
                        parser.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileLocationNameOriginal),
                            zippedStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zippedStream))
                            {
                                string line;
                                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    ZipReadTable.Rows.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I have tried converting the datatable to a string again, but the TextFieldParser isn't working with it (I think it is only for reading files?). Is the StreamWriter what I should be using? Thanks in advance StackOverFlow!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fairly simple solution:

```
    var ZipReadTable = new DataTable(); 
        ZipReadTable.Columns.Add("ZipCol1");

        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName), 
            zippedStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zippedStream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    ZipReadTable.Rows.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        string[] ParsedLine = null;
        string NotParsedLine = null;
        char Delimiter = '|';

        for (int k = 0; k < ZipReadTable.Rows.Count; k++)
        {
            NotParsedLine = ZipReadTable.Rows[k][0].ToString();
            ParsedLine = NotParsedLine.Split(Delimiter);
            OutputTable.Rows.Add(ParsedLine);
        }
        return (OutputTable);
```